# How do I get the latest commit in any branch?

Tags: gitlab

I would like to get the latest commit in any branch via GitLab API.

By default the [commits API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html) returns commits in the default branch (`GET /projects/:id/repository/commits`).

There is a `ref_name` parameter where I can specify the branch, but without knowing which branch contains the latest commit, I would have to try all branches?

Comment: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/get-all-commits-from-the-gitlab-api-of-all-branchs-is-it-possible/57372/2 suggests listing all branches then getting info for each branch. I guess automated date comparison of all first commits would do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information in one API call through the [Branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html).

To do so, make the request `GET /projects/:id/repository/branches`, then sort the returned list by either `commit.created_at`, `commit.authored_date`, or `commit.committed_date`, depending on your requirements. (Git allows a commit to have different authorship and committer information.)

Once you've sorted this list, the last element of that list is the most recent commit.